# How to remove word "null" from string in ActionScripts3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have code for convert each 2 numbers to a specific character, this code works, but output is with an unwanted word "null". I want to remove it. I can't identify which part of code is wrong.

```
var encoded_numbers:String = "102030";
var sub:String;
var decode_string:String;

for (var i2:int = 0; i2 < encoded_numbers.length; i2 += 2) 
{
    sub = encoded_numbers.charAt(i2) + encoded_numbers.charAt(i2 + 1);
    //trace(sub);

    switch(sub) 
   { 
    case "10": 
        decode_string += "A";
        break; 
    case "20": 
        decode_string += "B";
        break; 
    case "30": 
        decode_string += "C";
        break; 

   }

}
trace(decode_string);//convert
```

Output string:

```
nullABC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initial value of your decode_string is null. Just assign the initial value as follows:

```
var decodeString:String = "";
```

Comment: Thanks for your simple answer.

Answer (score 4):

> *"...but output is with an unwanted word "null". I want to remove it. I can't identify which part of code is wrong."*

When you say : `var decode_string:String;` you've **declared a variable but it has no value** so by default it gives result of "null". The problem later is when you use `+=` operator to further append your `ABC` letters, the final string has now become `nullABC`.

**To fix :**

Make your strings empty/blank (but never value-less) by using `String = "";`...

```
var encoded_numbers:String = "102030";
var sub:String = "";
var decode_string:String = "";
```

Also consider `substr` for extracting parts of texts (instead of `charAt`)..

```
for (var i2:int = 0; i2 < encoded_numbers.length; i2 += 2) 
{
    sub = encoded_numbers.substr(i2, 2); //gets 2 letters from position of i2
    //trace(sub);

    switch(sub) 
    { 
        case "10": 
            decode_string += "A";
            break; 
        case "20": 
            decode_string += "B";
            break; 
        case "30": 
            decode_string += "C";
            break; 

    }

}
trace(decode_string);//convert
```